# Insert multiple values by using Dynamic SQL from ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, insert

In SQL Server 2005 we can insert multiple values as

```
INSERT INTO
TableName
(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT
'text1', 'text2', 1
UNION ALL
'text3', 'text4', 2
```

How can I insert it using dynamic sql using `EXEC @sql`

When I run

```
EXEC '  INSERT INTO
    TableName
    (col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT
    ''text1'', ''text2'', 1 -- using double quotation marks to escape
    UNION ALL
    ''text3'', ''text4'', 2
 '
```

I get error saying

Incorrect syntax near

> 'INSERT INTO Tablename(col1, col2, col3) SELECT 'text1', 'text2', 1
> UNION ALL SELECT '.

Why it doesn't execute? Also, why the sql is not printing the whole sql statement that I typed? why it trims after the second select?

Can anyone help me write this?

**EDIT**

After I tried `Devart's` solution. It worked fine in SQL Server, and also from my ASP.NET application. But the problem comes when there is a space in any of the text say

```
EXEC ('
 INSERT INTO TableName (col1, col2, col3)
 SELECT ''text1'' AS t1, ''text2'' AS t2, 1 AS t3
 UNION ALL
 SELECT ''text3'', ''text4'', 2
')
```

this works fine...

but

```
EXEC ('
 INSERT INTO TableName (col1, col2, col3)
 SELECT ''text1'' AS t1, ''text2'' AS t2, 1 AS t3
 UNION ALL
 SELECT ''text3 with space in it'', ''text4 more spaces'', 2
')
```

**works fine only in SSMS but not** from asp.net application.

The code is as follows..

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand 
{ commandText = "myProcedure", commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, connection = myGlobalConnection };

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sqlParam", thatLongDynamicString);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

throw's an `Incorrect syntax error` near `with` and near `more`, **but** if there is no space in text column. It works fine.

Why is this happening?

Comment: You missed parentheses, it should be `exec('...')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL =  '
 INSERT INTO TableName (col1, col2, col3)
 SELECT ''text1'' AS t1, ''text2'' AS t2, 1 AS t3
 UNION ALL
 SELECT ''text3'', ''text4'', 2'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Or try this -

```
EXEC ('
 INSERT INTO TableName (col1, col2, col3)
 SELECT ''text1'' AS t1, ''text2'' AS t2, 1 AS t3
 UNION ALL
 SELECT ''text3'', ''text4'', 2
')
```

**Update:**

I think using `Dynamic SQL` in your case is bad practice. Try to use generate `XML` from your client and exec stored procedure with this `XML` as parameter. For example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.usp_InsertData') IS NOT NULL
   DROP PROCEDURE dbo.usp_InsertData
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_InsertData
    @Data XML
AS BEGIN

    --INSERT INTO <your_table> (...)
    SELECT 
          t.c.value('@col1', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        , t.c.value('@col2', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        , t.c.value('@col3', 'INT') 
    FROM @Data.nodes('root/item') t(c)

END
GO

DECLARE @XML XML
SELECT @XML = '
<root>
    <item col1="text3" col2="text4" col3="1"/>
    <item col1="text3 with space in it" col2="text4 more spaces" col3="2"/>
</root>'

EXEC dbo.usp_InsertData @XML
```

In output:

[image]

Comment: +1, though, aliasing columns in select list is not necessary for `insert into (...) select` (in contrast to `select ... into ..`)

Comment: @i-one you are right, but anyway using alias for columns is the good practice.

Comment: @Devart:
Really thanks! That solved the problem, but now I am stuck in something else, can you please check if you can help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. This will work.

```
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Sql = '
insert into temp (id,name,address) 
SELECT 1,''text1'', ''text2'' 
UNION ALL 
select 2,''text3'', ''text4'''

--PRINT @Sql
EXEC (@Sql)

SELECT *
FROM temp
```

You are missing `Select` after  `Union all`

> [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba59a/1)

```
**EDIT**
```

Try This C# code

```
    StringBuilder sbQuery = new StringBuilder();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con; //Your connection string"        
    sbQuery.Append("insert into temp (id,name,address) SELECT 1,'text1', 'text2' UNION ALL select 2,'text3', 'text4'"); // your query goes here
    cmd.CommandText = "Testing1"; // your procedure name
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SQL",sbQuery.ToString()));
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Your Store Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Testing1
@SQL varchar(Max)
AS
/* SET NOCOUNT ON */        
exec (@SQL)
select * from temp
RETURN
```